# Decoding File Encoded as Buffer In Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-s3

I am downloading an item from an S3 bucket using getObject.  I am able to receive the object as a JSON object with the correct ContentType of 'image/jpeg'. The picture data is encoded as in something I am not familiar with.  It starts with

```
<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46
```

And goes on for a large number of lines.  Calling JSON.stringify on the entire object converts the

```
"type": "Buffer",
      "data": [
        137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,
```

I am not familiar with how I should decode this in order to display an image given the ContentType information and the image data.  How do I convert the data into an image that I can display using a URL source tag?

I don't want to display the image directly from the source because I am trying to download the image and save it to local storage for display when the user is offline.

The image will be displayed in a react-native application using the  component.

Comment: It occurred to me that maybe I am trying to accomplish my task incorrectly.  Since maybe I'm not proposing the correct way to attempt to solve this problem, I'll be more broad. How do I download the image located at this URL https://s3.amazonaws.com/tour-story-pictures/us-east-1%3Aa35de631-846c-434d-b295-ee5d258856da/2d7feb23d49e79695af9683fbfaece06.png and display it in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either write it locally, or send it directly using streams with the correct mimetype.

Comment: i cannot elaborate my answer due to lack of information. the only information you provided was you are fetching something and then display it in react-native. so you will need to find out how you write or send through stream in your preferred language/framework

Comment: I'm using the fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the data from the server.  I'm hoping somebody will recognize the encoding which will enable me to figure out what exactly I'm receiving, and how to deal with it.

Comment: @reggie3 you will not need to download it if that path returns the image. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html you can use that path/url in the src directly.

Comment: My goal is to convert it to something that I can save on the user's device so that the image can be viewed while offline.  I won't know which file is the user will be using so I can't embed the file by using the require technique mentioned in the documentation.  The user could select a handful of any of hundreds of files.  Right now, I'm getting the buffer as shown in the original post.  What I'm receiving is representation of the file which itself was uploaded using the a base 64 encoding of a buffer created by using the 'result' method of the FileReader API.